# Confusion over `a` and `b` attributes from scipy.stats.uniform

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, distribution

Consider the following code:

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)  # gives 0.19.1

# Scipy.stats.uniform
unif = scipy.stats.uniform(1, 2)
print(unif.a, unif.b, unif.args) # gives a=0, b=1, args=(1,2)
```

It seems, regardless of the value I provide for `loc` and `scale`, the `uniform`-function returns `a=0,b=1`.

Compare that to e.g. `randint`:

```
# Scipy.stats.randint
randi = scipy.stats.randint(1, 10)
print(randi.a, randi.b, randi.args) # gives a=1, b=9, args=(1,10)
```

...which returns what I would expect.

So my question becomes: is this a bug in `scipy`, or have I misunderstood something? The `unif.args` value is set correctly though.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there any documentation indicating that `a` and `b` can be used to access the distribution's limits?

Comment: Also, note that in the case of `randint`  `a` and `p` do not follow the actual limits if you change loc (e.g. `randint(2, 7, loc=10)`).

Comment: No, I can't find that stated explicitly in the scipy documentation. I know I am making certain assumptions about the behavior of `uniform` here. I believe what throws me off, is the (seeming) difference to how `randint` behaves

Comment: Actually, I found this piece of documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous. Since uniform inherits from this class, I would actually expect `a,b` to be the bounds of the distribution.

Comment: I think the problem is that `uniform` is manipulated with parameters `loc` and `scale`. If you take another distribution, for example `truncnorm`, `a` and `b` also are only correct if you do not change `loc` and `scale`. So at least this seems to be consistent :) If it is a bug or a internal implementation detail I don't know for sure, but I would tend towards the latter, given the scarce documentation on the topic.

Comment: Yes, I think I may need to revise how I think of `a, b` -- the answers below certainly support your comments. I tend to think that parameters not prefixed by eiter `_` or `__` are "supposed" to be used by external code (rather than simply used for internal purposes only). Hope that made sense. I have removed any dependencies on `randi.a/.b` in my project. Cheers! /M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my understanding that the `a` and `b` are internal parameters, are not used in `scipy.stats.uniform`, because their normal functionality is basically duplicative of the `loc` and `scale` parameters.

As mentioned in the [`scipy.stats.uniform` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html) "This distribution is constant between `loc` and `loc` + `scale`."

So I don't think this is a bug, because the values of `a` and `b` should be treated as an implementation detail rather than a user-facing feature.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant source on this is [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L4924), abridged a bit:

```
class uniform_gen(rv_continuous):
    """A uniform continuous random variable.
    This distribution is constant between `loc` and ``loc + scale``.
    # ...
    """
    def _rvs(self):
        return self._random_state.uniform(0.0, 1.0, self._size)

   # ....
uniform = uniform_gen(a=0.0, b=1.0, name='uniform')
```

So `a` and `b` will always be 0 and 1, respectively.

I'm guessing your confusion (mine too occascionally with this notation) is that most textbooks will define uniform distributions as lying [between *a* and *b*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).  But in this case `a` and `b` are something a bit [different](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L1323) and, as @jakevdp said,

> This distribution is constant between `loc` and `loc + scale`.

So relating this back to the traditional definition, think of *a* as `loc` and *b* as `loc + scale`.

(The parent class `rv_continuous` in turn is defined [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L4924) if you're interested.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have revised my code and removed any dependencies on `a, b` (acutally, `.args` works just fine as well). I wouldn't necessarily say that I was confused by generic textbook definitions -- just general ignorance ;-)