# Ann mean for function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am looking for an networks. I cant understand that in this page  [link](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/)

why we multiply with 2 and after that extract 1 for mean?

i know the mean is only: `(a+b)/2` so why "2" and "-1" in that code:

```
 syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1
```

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with the mean? It looks like it is just a layer of weights initialized randomly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion over \`a\` and \`b\` attributes from scipy.stats.uniform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846752/confusion-over-a-and-b-attributes-from-scipy-stats-uniform)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for numpy's `np.random.random` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html)

It says

> Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated interval. To sample `Unif[a, b), b > a` multiply the output of random_sample by `(b-a)` and add `a`:
>
> `(b - a) * random_sample() + a`

So it would seem that the author wanted to sample from a uniform distribution on the interval `[1, 3)`.